# Understanding how 'switch' and 'if' statements can be used for the same result

Tags: javascript

As part of exam preparations, students are given a set of possible questions. One of them baffles me and I cannot acquire answer to it by myself.
The question goes like this (literary copy-paste):

Given a statement,

```
switch (x) {
    case 0: x=1; break;
    default: x=0;
}
```

How could you use `if` statement to get the same result?

To this, there are four possible answers you can choose.

1. `if (x===0) x=1; else x=0;`
2. `if (x) x=1; x = 0;`
3. `if (x) x=1; else x=0;`
4. `if (x===0) x=1; if (x!=0) x=0;`

Can please somebody explain to me the proper solution to this question?

Comment: Do you know what `switch` does? And what `if` does?

Comment: Look into this response to [`switch/if statements`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38685722/6445533).

Comment: only one returns the same results for the same input - try it yourself

Comment: What do you think the answer should be? Try to  see what the code is doing logically in both cases.

Comment: The answer is (1) and it uses strict type checking. Number (4) does not consider the strict type because it does not use "!==".

Comment: @MartinLottering (4) is also wrong because after setting `x` to `1`, the predicate is `true` in the subsequent `if` statement and it gets set back to `0` again. In the end, both (2) and (4) are equivalent to the simple instruction `x = 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer there would be 1.

The switch statement you supplied is basically as follows.

```
Based on the value of X do the following;
If X is equal to 0, make x equal 1.
Otherwise, make x equal 0.
```

There are different situations which make one more ideal than the other.

---

Edit:

```
switch (x) - This translates roughly to the 'if (x === )' part of the if statement.
case 1     - This is the second paramater in the if, in this case it would be 'if (x === 1)'
case 2     - This is again the second paramater in the if, in this case it would be 'if (x === 2)'
case "3"   - This is again second paramater in the if, in this case it would be 'if (x === "3")'
default    - This defines the 'default' operation, which evaluates to the 'else' part of an if statement.
```

Taking this into account, the above statement could be as follows;

```
switch (x):
    case 1:
        x = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        x = 2;
        break;
    case "3":
        x = "3";
        break;
    default:
        x = 0
        break;
```

As an if statement, it would be as follows;

```
if (x === 1) {
    x = 1;
} else if (x === 2) {
    x = 2
} else if (x === "3") {
    x = "3"
} else {
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: "Make x equal to 1" - and stop processing the switch-case by calling `break;`.

Comment: `Otherwise` kinda implies that

Comment: I was doing a more generalised, English and almost pseudo version translation to 'IF' logic, but yes, you are correct in terms of how the switch/case is operating.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!

Answer (score 0):

1st seems the answer. It will check for type and value. If it is 0 then it will assign 1 to x else 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. x===0 matches value and types of both operands.Your first condition will set x to 1 if its 0 , else 0
2. It ultimately sets x to 0
3. if x has false,null,undefined,0 it will be set to 0 else 1
4. x will always be 0

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is `if (x===0) x=1; else x=0;`

So only if the `x` is `0` x should be `1` otherwise (`default:` statement) assign `0`