# Javascript equivalent of CASE expression

Tags: javascript

In SQL and PL/SQL we can have a CASE **expression** like this:

```
y := case x
     when 1 then 'foo'
     when 5 then 'bar'
     when 7 then 'baz'
     else 'wak'
     end;
```

The simplest **expression** of this type I can think of in javascript is to use nested ternary operators, like this:

```
y = (x==1)
    ? "foo"
    :( (x==5)
       ? "bar"
       :( (x==7)
          ? "baz"
          : "wak"
          )))
```

Is there a simpler/clearer way to form this sort of thing as an **expression**?

NOTE: I know about the `switch` **statement**, but here I'm looking for an **expression**.

Comment: What is called `case` in Pascal en PL/SQL, is called [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in many other programming languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript switch() or if()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711347/javascript-switch-or-if)

Comment: Many C-like languages have a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

Comment: @GolezTrol, can you give a working example? When I try something like `y = switch(x) { case(1):"foo" }` I get "Unexpected token switch".

Comment: @JeffreyKemp because the `switch` statement is a **statement**, not an expression. Just like `if`.

Comment: Yes, why do you think I asked the question? I specifically asked for an **expression**.

Comment: Everyone, please note that while I'm not an expert in javascript, I have used it enough to know about the `switch` statement. I'm looking for an **expression**, please.

Comment: Um, I don't know if my question wasn't clear, but I *never suggested the switch statement*! And you're wrong about SQL and PL/SQL, the CASE expression is supported at least in Oracle SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp In PL/SQL program code you can't use it, only in SQL (including SQL that is embedded in PL/SQL). I misunderstood your question because you explicitly mentioned PL/SQL, sorry. Anyway, [I provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542183/511529) using an arrow function. I'm not sure if the syntax is going to make it easier (depends on the situation), but I think it is closest to what you're looking for. There is no formal case/switch expression in JS, so it's going to be a function, or a trick using an object, or by nesting ternary operators.

Comment: @GolezTrol, yes, you most certainly can. Thanks for your contributions here anyway.

Comment: @GolezTrol, `case when x=y then z end` **is** supported as an expression in PL/SQL.

Comment: e.g. `dbms_output.put_line(case when 1=1 then 'hello' else 'goodbye' end);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a key-value map

```
y = {1: "foo", 5: "bar", 7: "then"}[x] || "wak";
```

or if the map is bigger or you use falsy values, ...

```
var map = {
    1: "foo",
    5: "bar",
    7: "then"
};

y = x in map? map[x]: "wak";
```

Comment: The first option was exactly what I was looking for. It leads to clean code that is relatively easy to read and understand, and it can be used anywhere a javascript expression is expected.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp but as mentioned, be careful when your expression returns falsy values, like `0` or empty String, or `null`, ... Then the `||`-version will fall back to the default value although your expression returned a value. Then you need to use the second variant wich explicitely tests wether this key is defined on the map and falls back to default only if it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement:

```
switch(x) {
  case 1:
    y = 'foo';
    break;
  case 5:
    y = 'bar';
    break;
  case 7:
    y = 'baz';
    break;
  default:
    y = 'wak';
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you absolutely *need* an expression, you could use an object as a key-value map, like this:

```
y = {
    1: 'foo',
    5: 'bar',
    7: 'baz',
  }[x] || 'wak';
```

Comment: I'm looking for an **expression**, not a statement.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` is the typical translation for `case`, but it's not an expression. You could assign to `y` inside the statement, though. Note that you'll need `break` to prevent the case from bubbling on and return the next result:

```js
var y, x = 7;

switch (x) {
    case 1: y = 'foo'; break;
    case 5: y = 'bar'; break;
    case 7: y = 'baz'; break;
    default: y = 'wak'; break;
  }

console.log(y);
```

Given that you are looking for an *expression*, you could make a function:

```js
function getY(x) 
{
  switch (x) {
    case 1: return 'foo';
    case 5: return 'bar';
    case 7: return 'baz';
    default: return 'wak';
  }
}
 
y = getY(7);
console.log(y);
```

Alternatively, you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
y = ((x) => {
  switch (x) {
    case 1: return 'foo';
    case 5: return 'bar';
    case 7: return 'baz';
    default: return 'wak';
  }})(7);
    
console.log(y);
```

There is also a flavor in between using an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), but in essence it's the same as the other two.

Comment: There's no need to do `break` after `return`.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting alternative, but it's quite a bit more complex than a key-value map IMHO.

Comment: I think this syntax is more flexible, so you may want to keep it in mind for other scenarios, but indeed, the key-map (actually just an object) is an awesome solution for this scenario. Cheers to @Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Your key to search is [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case.

```
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        //code  
        break;
    case 5:
        //code  
        break;
    // more cases
    default:
       // code  
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an **expression**, not a statement.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Why to write complex expressions, where as switch evaluating your simple expressions ?

Comment: Because **switch** is a **statement**. If I wanted to write procedural logic I would. In my case I need to supply an **expression**.

Answer (score 1):

Use object literal :

```
v = { ...  }[expression];


y = {1: 'foo', 5: 'bar', 7: 'baz'}[x] || 'wak';
```

Caution: if you need the else clause as shown none of the case values should be a Javascript falsy.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably suggest a switch statement as shown here

```
var y;
switch(expression) {
    case 1:
    y = 'foo';
    break;
case 5:
    y = 'bar';
    break;
default:
    y = 'wak';
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: I'm looking for an **expression**, not a statement.